# Find similarity in a very precise numerical environment

Tags: python, nlp, spacy

I have a list of 100+ sentences, and I need to find which is the closest to a user prompt.
The thing is that we are dealing with very precise, nuanced prompt, because we analyze numeric data.
Eaxmple:

```
1. Did variable x changed at least 5% in the past week ?
2. show me variable x change in the past week
```

In this example, sentence 1 and 2 are **totally different in the context of a chart but similar in the global context**, but most simple models like `spaCY` will rate them as very similar (0.9+) because they have many similar words.

What is the way to go to be able to train a model or to use a trained model, to find similarity in a very precise numerical environment like this, where sentences have many similar words but have total different meaning ?

I used this `spaCY` model:

```
prompt_doc = nlp(user_prompt)
similarities = []

 
for sentence in sentences:
    sentence_doc = nlp(sentence)
    similarity = prompt_doc.similarity(sentence_doc)
    similarities.append(similarity)
    print("Sentence:", sentence)
    print("Similarity rating:", similarity)
    print()
```

The result for 100 sentences like the above, was that all of them have around 0.8-0.9 similarity. Which is very wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried using [Google's Universal Sentence Encoder](https://tfhub.dev/google/universal-sentence-encoder/4)?

Here's a code snippet which uses the encoder (I used Google Colab to run the code). For your example it returns a similarity of 0.6643186, much lower than the similarity you get with `spaCy`.

**Some additional info:** Looking at the `spaCy` [documentation](https://spacy.io/usage/linguistic-features#vectors-similarity) about `similarity`, it seems like `spaCy` uses non-contextualized word vectors in conjunction with vector averaging to compute the similarities, which is the reason why it doesn't work for you: `spaCy`'s implementation does neither consider word order nor context of a word. In contrast, Google's `Universal Sentence Encoder` will give you one single vector for an entire sentence, thereby considering both word order and context of the word.

Let me know if this helps!

```
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
import tensorflow_hub as hub

module_url = "https://tfhub.dev/google/universal-sentence-encoder/4"
model = hub.load(module_url)

def embed(input):
  return model(input)


sentence_1 = "Did variable x changed at least 5% in the past week ?"
sentence_2 = "show me variable x change in the past week"

embeddings = embed([sentence_1, sentence_2])
corr = np.inner(embeddings[0], embeddings[1])

print(corr)  # 0.6643186
```